# Phantom type 'a' is a rigid type variable

Tags: haskell

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = pure ()

data P a = P Int 
data D1
data D2

class C a where
instance C D1 where
instance C D2 where

mkP_D1 :: Int -> P D1
mkP_D1 = P

mkP_D2 :: Int -> P D2
mkP_D2 = P

ps :: C a => [P a]
ps = [mkP_D1 1, mkP_D2 2] 

qs :: Num a => [a]
qs = [1, 2]
```

gives compiler error

- Couldn't match type 'a' with 'D1'
  'a' is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for:
  ps :: forall a. C a => [P a]

  Expected type: P a
  Actual type: P D1
- In the expression: mkP_D1 1
  In the expression: [mkP_D1 1, mkP_D2 2]
  In an equation for 'ps': ps = [mkP_D1 1, mkP_D2 2]
- Relevant bindings include
  ps :: [P a]

  line 22:  ps = [mkP_D1 1, mkP_D2 2]

Why is it that `qs` works fine, but yet `ps` does not?

Comment: In `qs` both elements of the list are of the same type `a`, while in `ps` they're of different types `P D1` and `P D2`. The equivalent non-working version of `qs` would be `qs = [ (1 :: Int), (2 :: Double) ]`

Comment: But in `ps` the constraint is being satisfied, so why does the compiler complain?

Comment: Elements of the list must be all of the same type. Not of different types that all satisfy the same constraint, but of the same type.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a list of existentially quantified values, each wrapped up with its own constraint? Then change the type to `ps :: [(forall a. C a => P a)]`, that should work.

Comment: That is what I am looking for apparently. Compiler suggested I use extension `RankNTypes`, but then complained     

    * Illegal polymorphic type: `forall a. C a => P a`
    

GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
    * In the type signature: `ps :: [(forall a. C a => P a)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to provide some intuition, simplifying things a bit.

`ps :: C a => [P a]` is a contract between the implementation of `ps` and its user. According to it,

- the user can choose any `a`
- the user must prove that `C a` holds
- then, the implementation must provide a value of type `[P a]`.

For instance, the user could choose `a ~ D1`. The instance is then used to prove `C D1`, so the contract is satisfied. The implementation must then, in this case, provide a value of type `[P D1]`.

Your implementation is `[mkP_D1 1, mkP_D2 2]`. For the above case, the value `mkP_D1 1` follows the contract since it's a `P D1`. However, `mkP_D2 2` is not a `P D1` (but is a `P D2`), violating the contract.

Since there is an instance where the user fulfills the contract but the implementation does not, the code is rejected by the type checker.

More pedantically, the issue here is that `a` is chosen by the user, *not* the implementation. If the implementation tries to choose some specific type `a`, there is a chance the user will pick something else, and the compiler will rightfully complain in that case.

> Why is it that `qs` works fine?

```
qs :: Num a => [a]
qs = [1, 2]
```

Here the user chooses `a`, but `qs` does not. Indeed, `1` is of any (numeric) type `a`, and so is `2`.

Compare this with `ps`, which tries to choose `a`. Incidentally, `ps` not only tries to chooses `a` to be `D1` (which would already trigger the "rigid variable" error), but also tries to choose `a` to be `D2` (which makes the situation even worse).

A possible working implementation is to add a method to the class:

```
class C a where
  mkP :: Int -> P a

instance C D1 where
  mkP = P

instance C D2 where
  mkP = P

ps :: C a => [P a]
ps = [mkP 1, mkP 2]
```

Note that this is only an example. You could use `P` directly and avoid introducing the new method in the class.

Comment: Aha, so it's the same problem for `qs = [1::Int]`

Comment: @LoHaBuyshan Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

All elements of a list must have the same type. `qs` works because all its elements have the same type `a`. `ps` doesn't work, because its first element has type `P D1` and its second element has type `P D2`. Different types. No can do.

From the comments, it became evident that what you're really looking for is for each value to have a different `Dx` and pack its own constraint `C` with it. To achieve that, wrap it in a GADT:

```
data PP where
  PP :: forall a. C a => P a -> PP

ps :: [PP]
ps = [PP (mkP_D1 1), PP (mkP_D2 2)]
```

Here, the constructor `PP` packs inside of it not only a value `P a`, but also the type `a` and its corresponding constraint `C a`.

**Q: Ooooh, but that's so inconvenient! I have to wrap every value in `PP`! Can't I do without that?**

Short answer - no, you can't. As stated before, all elements of a list must have the same type, period. And if you want to jam different types in there, you have to wrap their differences somehow so they're not visible anymore.